# Android: Converting phone sound file to raw data

Tags: android, audio, mp3, data-extraction

I would like to take the music files from my phone (mp3 mostly) and convert them to raw data that FFT can be done on. Is there anyway to do this by using the android/java framework or do I need to integrate something like LAME to decode the mp3?

Comment: LAME isn't a decoder, it's an encoder. That's what the E in LAME stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to need LAME to decode this to a file, you could have the Android system decode it for you but it would just go to the speakers unless you used kernel hacks to allow sending it direct to file.